# How can I take off www(sub-domain) if url contains it?

Tags: nginx

I've just switched from Apache to Nginx.
Then I'm stucked with this problem.
When I was using Apache, first `www(sub-domain)` could be removed automatically by having this `.htaccess`
If I want the same on Nginx, how can I do that?

Here's my old `.htaccess`

**.htaccess** (I was using this when I was using Apache)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(test-sample-site\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Then here's my current conf for `Nginx`

**etc/nginx/conf.d/rails.conf**

```
upstream sample {
    ip_hash;
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn/unicorn_sample.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sample.jp;
    root /var/www/html/sample/public;

    location /wiki {
        alias /usr/share/wiki;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/wiki.+\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/wiki(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/wiki$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://sample;
            break;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/assets|system/ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
upstream sample {
    ip_hash;
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn/unicorn_sample.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sample.jp;
    root /var/www/html/sample/public;

    location /wiki {
        alias /usr/share/wiki;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/wiki.+\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/wiki(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/wiki$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://sample;
            break;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/assets|system/ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

server {          # <== redirection server block
    server_name www.sample.jp;
    return 301 sample.jp$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this server block to your config ( at the bottom or top, but outside the other server block )

```
server {
    server_name www.sample.jp;
    return 301 sample.jp$request_uri;
}
```

Your can add it to your config like this

```
upstream sample { # <== upstream block
    # ...
}
server {          # <== server block
    # ....
}
server {          # <== redirection server block
    server_name www.sample.jp;
    return 301 sample.jp$request_uri;
}
```

As for what it would do, the `$request_uri` will append every thing that was in the original URL to the new one, for example

```
http://www.example.com/a/b/c
```

`$request_uri` = `/a/b/c`

new URL will be

```
http://example.com/a/b/c
```

I believe it should append the query string too, the `?x=y` part in `http://example.com/a/b?x=y`

Comment: Could you add your code to my original code and show me please?

Comment: and does it cover the URL something like `www.sample.jp/test1/test2`? does it take to `sample.jp/test1/test2`?

Comment: Thanks for updating. But now it redirected to the url `http://www.sample.jp/sample.jp/sample.jp/sample.jp/sample.jp/sample.jp/sample.jp/sample.jp/...same repeat` when I tried to access `http://www.sample.jp`

Comment: That could mean that it's always matching the redirection server block, means there might be a mistake in the `server_name` in either server blocks.

Comment: I updated my question. Please see my **UPDATE**. That's what I tried